# How to view a page's source when a javascript modal popup loads first?

Tags: firefox, html, javascript

Scenario:

You go to a page.  Before loading, a javascript modal popup loads.  Firebug has yet to pick up on the source.  However, this code is obviously living in your browser.  How can you view the source, at this time?

EDIT:  It appears that this popup is not javascript driven.  I have disabled javascript and it still loads.  However, it definitely looks like javascript... How would this occur without javscript?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the popup...

Comment: i'm not suer where icould upload a screenshot.  it appears that when a file is being authorized by .htaccess, you can not load the page source beforehand.  i didn't know this.  does this sound like the answer?

Comment: If it's a .htaccess login box then the browser isn't sent anything until you log in - do you see a login prompt?
You can use (for example) http://tinypic.com/ for screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try prepending 'view-source:' to the URL;

```
view-source:http://www.google.co.uk
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: check this out : http://bedaux.net/cpp2html/ the popup that comes up has no editable address bar and greyed out "save page as" or "show source code" options. how do you do then ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use firefox, you can select text/item/etc at the popup and click in context menu on "show source code for selection".

or better

Firefox Addon - [Web Developer 1.1.8](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/60)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the firefox plugin called JSView.  This is how I have been getting around these types of roadblocks.

[JSView is available here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addons/policy/0/2076/34062?src=addondetail)

Comment: I've just downloaded this plugin.  I've obviously never used it, but it doesn't appear that I can use it (on right click) on this popup.

Comment: this is probably due to my new realization that i've posted as an edit to the question.  Hm..

Comment: You actually have to explictly run JSView from the tools menu at the top of FF